# how to define new line character with UDL in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

my requirement is with specific character/ operator i would like to take it to new line. 
example:

```
| makemv delim=";" PrismCr   | mvexpand PrismCr | eval PrismCr = round(PrismCr,0)  | search PrismCr=$CR$
```

if i take | as a new line character then above one should appear like

```
| makemv delim=";" PrismCr   
| mvexpand PrismCr 
| eval PrismCr = round(PrismCr,0)  
| search PrismCr=$CR$
```

is there a way to define in UDL on Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've done for Notepad ++

1. Paste the syntax to a new document
2. Apply a UDL for the data format I am looking at (I use X12 data a lot which no plugins help with)
3. I recorded a macro that I set a find and replace to that looks like this
   Find: ~
   Replace: ~\r\n

Unfortunately, it is still several clicks with the UDL and Macro but it is much faster than before. I have not found a way to do a new line in the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to define that.
I don't know any text editor where you can define your own newline character.

You can still find `\|` and replace it for `\r\n|` in **Search mode** = **Extended** in order to get your result. (And when you are done witch edits, you can search/replace in reverse manner.)